# How to implement Twitter sign in using only Twitter kit 3 and oAuth in IOS application with swift?

Tags: swift, twitter, twitter-oauth

I'm having a problem with "Twitter LOGIN in SWIFT 3" using Twitter-kit 3.
I'm getting ”Could not authenticate you” error and I did not use OAuth. I don't know how to implement it using OAuth.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to share any code that shows what you're doing to implement the login flow when you get this error? Have you implemented the [callback handler](https://dev.twitter.com/twitterkit/ios/log-in-with-twitter) for `application:openURL:options` that is required?